# CakePhp validate a select field with values from other model

Tags: validation, cakephp, select, field

I created a vue for my `register` action in `MembersController`. But when I add a field called `memberType` using values from `MemberType` model. I can't validate this field. I am open to any suggestions, thanks! :)

**View** `add`

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->create('Member', array(
        "type" => "file",
        "url"  => array("controller" => "Member", "action" => "add"),
        "inputDefaults" => array("class" => "form-control", "div" => "form-group")
    ));

    echo $this->Form->input("Member.NAME", array(
        "error" => array(
            "attributes" => array("escape" => false, "wrap" => "span", "class" => "alert-danger")
        )
    ));

    echo $this->Form->input("Membertype", array(
        "type" => "select",
        "empty" => true,
        "error" => array(
            "attributes" => array("escape" => false, "wrap" => "span", "class" => "alert-danger")
        )
    ));

    echo $this->Form->end(array(
        "label" => "Register",
        "class" => "btn btn-primary"
    ));
?>
```

**Controller** `MemberController`

```
<?php
class MembresController extends AppController {
    public function register(){
        $this->set('membertypes', $this->Member->MemberType->find('list'));

        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->Membre->create();
            if ($this->Membre->save(array(
                "Membre" => array(
                    "NAME" => $this->request->data["NAME"],
                    "type_id" => $this->request->data["Membertype"],
                )
            ))) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(
                    'Registred',
                    "default",
                    array("class" => "alert alert-success")
                );
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash(
                "Not registered",
                "default",
                array("class" => "alert alert-danger")
            );
        }
    }
}
```

`Members` table :

```
create table Member
(
   ID                   int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
   type_id              int not null,
   NOM                  varchar(255) not null,
   primary key (ID)
);
```

`MemberType` table :

```
create table MemberType
(
   ID                   int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
   NAME                 varchar(255) not null,
   primary key (ID)
);
```

Comment: I think you should  check validate data for `Member` model. You want to check validation for `Member`  model only in controller???

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the official way to do it, but you can validate those fields if they're nested within your data-array..

```
$saveData = [
'YourSavingModel' =>  [
   'name' => 'blub',
   'MemberType' => [whatever]
]
```

Now you can add 'MemberType' to your $model->validate and it will also validate those values based on your rules..

Note that it won't save the info this way.

After validating you need to alter the array to the way you have it now.